# Selenium not turning results when after signing into website

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to make a bot that web scrapes a website. I have got it to the stage in which it puts in the user name and pass word. The website then takes me to a different URL, (from the portal to the home page). The bot cannot seem to find any elements on this new home page. The URL has changed, and I believe that the code is not scraping this new page. How do I update the code, if I simply use the URL of the home page, the website then asks for the username and password again.

I have provided code below that has the same problem, except this time with searching google and then finding the elements as I do not wish to provide personal details about the website I am scraping.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys("github")
search_bar.submit()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("LC20lb DKV0Md")
print(element)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.close()

# If I was to try and find any of the elements on this page using driver.find_element_by_class_name, it would result in the following error message  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="inputfield"]"}
#   (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
driver.close()
```

Edit:
I am on Windows 10 and using Google chrome
Edit 2:

I believe it may have something to do with the driver scraping the old URL, rather then the new URL that has been searched and contains the search results, is there anyway to perhaps update which URL it is scraping

Answer (score 0):

try to use implicitly_wait instead of sleep

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys("github")
search_bar.submit()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.close()
```

Comment: This still does not work, as I get the following error: `message:selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="sfbg"]"
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)`

Comment: The message you get is from running the code provided above?   the css element ('sfbg') that was not found is not related to the example

Comment: No, Sorry, that code works, but if after the bot searches for github using google, If i then try and then find any elements on that page, that error occurs

Comment: can you share the example you are running?

Comment: I am using `element = driver.find_element_by_name('sfbg')`. This does not result in any being found, despite the fact that it worked when it was used to find the search bar. Thank you for your help so far.